# how to remove append span tag by jquery

Tags: scripting

I past my code here html and jquery. Please tell me that how can i remove append value by jquery here.

html:

Hello X

click

jquery:

$("p").click(function(){
    $("#editable").append("Hello X ");
});
$(".sp").click(function(){
$(this).remove();
});

// output: Hello X Hello X Hello X Hello X Hello X Hello X Hello X Hello X
click

I want remove hello string on the click on hello string/X.

Comment: why do you think a JavaScript/JQuery question is on-topic on a site that is called "database administrators"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name heh, nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

var txt=

```
'Hello <a class="sp">X</a>'
```

$("p").click(function(){

```
  $("#editable").append(txt);
```

});

$(".sp").click(function(){
       $(this).remove(); 
 });